# How to combine "toon-diffuse" shader and "toon glossy" shader?

Tags: node-editor

What is the best way to combine these two shaders? When I use the "add shader", it doesn't just combine the shaders, but it masses up the colors and the lighting. What would be some of the best ways to do that?

Comment: Could you describe how you want them to be combined? Perhaps with some images showing what aspects of the shaders you want to keep in the mixed version?

Comment: Just like in the internal blender engine where there is a toon material-toon diffuse and toon specular, but in cycles they are separate. How to combine them? Or maybe the specular is something else then the "toon-glossy" node? What is it?

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5740/599

Comment: For example, if you render an object in blender internal with the toon material without the specular and then if you make a second render with the same material, but this time with the specular toon material too, the diffuse of the two renders should be the same regardless if on the other render the object has a specular on it. How to do that in cycles?

Comment: Both the mix node and the add node fit that criteria..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the material properties you could setup a [*Mix-Shader*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Render/Cycles/Nodes/Shaders):

[image]

Or switch to the Node-Editor where it is more clearly arranged:

[image]

Comment: thanks. Yeah, I thought of the mix shader at first, but it doesn't combine them with the full values, it just mixes them.

Answer (score 3):

I reccomend a *Mix Shader*. If you want it to combine it in a different way, you can always attach nodes like *Color Ramp* or *Fresnel* to the `Fac` value to change the output.