# How can I use the BI Noise Texture in Cycles?

Tags: materials

Okay,so I kept watching the FNaF material video by Emil "Ace" Macko wondering how to make the most accurate FNaF toy material. I tried Then I see the new toy models made by Everything_Animations and the material in the image is the most accurate. So I was wondering,how do you make the exact same procedural texture that Everything_Animations made,but for Blender Cycles?
[image]

[image]

I found out that the material in Blender Internal is the hardened version of the Blender Original clouds texture with an inverted Colorramp and what I want is that I want to use the same kind of texture for the glossy specularity using the Cloud Noise listed in the description but in Blender Cycles without using an image texture because of seam marks.

Comment: read this question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5740/how-to-get-blender-internal-like-specularity-in-cycles/5742#5742

Comment: I've been trying to mirror the cloud noise texture types from Blender Internal into Blender Cycles but so far I haven't gotten any luck,and in Blender Internal,I've been trying to render it with a blue spot light,an orange hemi,and a white area facing the model's front,but it doesn't show up on the mask and it's cheeks,lips,or tears

Comment: Please someone,what I wanted to do is to use Blender Internal textures in Blender Cycles,and now you're hating on me just because you can't give an answer,well that isn't fair to anyone.
Please help me.
I found that the texture is a hardened version of the Blender Original cloud noise but with an inverted Color Ramp.
How do I make this texture,I can't use images because there are seams,please.
Please help me.

Comment: The Cloud Noise I'm talking about is most commonly used for specularity for FNaF toy animatronic suit material in Blender Internal/Blender Render.

What can I do to get this texture for the glossy specularity without using an image because of obvious seam marks?

Comment: You are not getting answers because it is not clear what you are after. Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of the question, and clarify it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is "you can't." There is not a 1:1 correlation between Blender Internal materials and Cycles materials. The Clouds material is similar to the Noise node in Cycles, but not quite the same.

The longer answer is that you can make just about any kind of material you need to in either renderer, but you'll have to use different techniques from one to the other. You should start with the Noise node in Cycles, and then tweak it until you get something that looks like what you want. You'll have to play with the settings on the Noise node itself, but you'll almost certainly need to add a Ramp node to control the hardness of the noise.

Anything beyond that is really outside the scope of this site. Please keep in mind that it's **not a forum.** This is a Q&A site. We love to help, but this site works differently than most people expect. It's not designed to handle conversations, rather it's designed to handle discreet questions with clear answers.

Hope that helps!

Comment: I can't...Okay then,can someone please create a node that allows the use of both Blender Internal and Blender Cycles.

Comment: Wait a minute,is it possible to create Blender Cycles lighting in Blender Internal?

Comment: What if you can just use the same lighting settings in Blender Internal?

Is there a way for that to happen?

Every time that I use lighting in Blender Internal,the said specularity texture doesn't show up.

I wonder why?

Comment: It's not as simple as creating a node to use both BI and Cycles. They're fundamentally different. It's like the difference between steering a car and steering a ship. They both have wheels... but you can't just swap one wheel for the other and make your car into a ship.

Comment: As for lighting, Cycles is (sort of... VERY sort of) doing the same thing as what BI calls Global Illumination (GI). You can use GI to achieve a similar effect as in Cycles, but the whole reason Cycles was developed is because it's MUCH more efficient than BIGI.

Comment: The specular texture doesn't show up in BI because BI's materials are set up very differently from Cycles' materials. It **is** possible to use spec maps in BI, you'll just have to look into that. Note that BI technically *can* use nodes, but they're far less powerful that Cycles' nodes. You'll probably have to learn how to use BI's regular, non-node materials.

Comment: When I meant lighting,I meant lamps.

Comment: Yes, and my answer is the same. The lights are all the same in both BI and Cycles (mostly), but they will look different because Cycles ONLY does Global illumination, and Blender Internal BARELY does Global Illumination.

Comment: One more question,can you import material from 3D Studio Max into Blender?

Answer (score -1):

I'm back and I'm finally giving you all the solution to this enigma. A couple of months ago, with a little help from someone and some experimenting of my own, I found the answer. It's actually a lot easier than it looks.

1. Add a Noise Texture node, set the scale to 8. For me, I set the detail to 16. It's necessary if you want it to be realistic.
2. Add two Colorramp nodes and set them to B-Spline mode. Set the black color stop on Colorramp 1 to 0.046 and reverse the color stops on the second one. Plug the values into the Fac. sockets of both Colorramps.
3. Add a Math node and set it to Maximum mode. Plug both Colorramps into the node with the first one on top.
4. Add another Math node and turn Clamp mode on. Set it to Add, plug the Maximum node into the top socket and set the bottom value to -0.05.
5. Add a Bright/Contrast node and plug the Add node into the color socket. Set the brightness to 0.2 and the contrast to 1.000. If you want to use the inverted version for matte plastic, set the brightness to -0.125 and the contrast to 1.1 then add an Invert node set to 1 and plug the Bright/Contrast node into it. If you want to use both at the same time, plug them both into a MixRGB node and switch between them when you feel like it. For me, I put an Invert node with black in the color input and I plugged it into the MixRGB Fac socket.
6. Plug the MixRGB node into the Blender Guru's Less/More node group. If you don't have it, you can obtain it easily online. Here's the link: https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/making-realistic-pbr-materials-part-2-metal?rq=PBR
7. Add yet another MixRGB node and set it to Multiply. Plug the Less/More group into the Fac. of the new MixRGB node. Set the bottom color code to #BCBCBC and the top color to #E0E0E0. The bottom color is for roughness.

After this is all said and done, you'll get something like this:
[image]

I hope this helps you all as this has helped me. To make it easier, you can turn this into a simple node group. Create a roughness slider and plug it into the Multiply MixRGB node's second color input. This is the solution to my problems. An answer to the prayers of FNaF modelers everywhere.

Comment: Sorry for the three dots in front of hey. Now,every time I try to begin my sentence with a word with a capital letter,it always deletes it. How do I stop this?